# How to add active class on div on link click inside of div

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I want to add active class to the parent element of the div, but the problem is this code is adding on double click not on single click, how to fix this.

The below code is for the sidebar which I want to show on my website, everything is fine but the problem is the handleActiveClass function is not working on single click.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Sidebar.css';

const Sidebar = ({ sidebarOpen, closeSidebar, handleLogout }) => {
  let logoUrl = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('app_icon'));

  const handleActiveClass = (e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('active_menu_link');
  };

  return (
    <div id='sidebar' className={sidebarOpen ? 'sidebar-responsive' : ''}>
      <div className='sidebar_title'>
        <div className='sidebar_img'>
          <img src={`https://stucharge.bakersbrisk.com${logoUrl}`} alt='logo' />
          <h1>Admin Panel</h1>
        </div>
        <i className='fa fa-times' id='sidebaricon' onClick={closeSidebar}></i>
      </div>
      <div className='sidebar_menu'>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fa fa-home'></i>
          <Link to='/home'>Dashboard</Link>
        </div>
        <h2>MNG</h2>

        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fas fa-user-circle'></i>
          <Link to='/profile'>Profile </Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fas fa-book'></i>
          <Link to='/subjects'>Subjects </Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fa fa-graduation-cap'></i>
          <Link to='/courses'>Courses</Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fas fa-book-open'></i>
          <Link to='/notes'>Notes</Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fas fa-chalkboard-teacher'></i>
          <Link to='/class'>Online Class</Link>
        </div>
        <div className='sidebar_link ' onClick={(e) => handleActiveClass(e)}>
          <i className='fa fa-handshake-o'></i>
          <Link to='/contact'>Contact Developer</Link>
        </div>
        <h2>LEAVE</h2>
        <div className='sidebar_logout'>
          <i className='fa fa-power-off'></i>
          <Link to='/' onClick={handleLogout}>
            Log out
          </Link>
        </div>
        <div
          className='dev'
          style={{ position: 'absolute', bottom: '20px', left: '8px' }}
        >
          <h3 style={{ color: '#51c4d3' }}>
            Developed by{' '}
            <i
              className='far fa-thumbs-up'
              style={{ fontSize: '1.6rem', marginLeft: '4px' }}
            ></i>
          </h3>
          <h2 style={{ color: '#b0efeb' }}>Codeven Solution</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This code might not run here, but you can understand it as i have pasted the whole code.

Comment: What tutorial are you following that has you produce this kind of code?

Comment: I have done it on my own, and I know it's 100% wrong please help me find solution to this.

Comment: If you want to use React, the 'getting started' guide is a good place to start: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: @Harshitkumar Unable to run the snippet. Can you fix that?

Comment: You might try removing the script elements.